# Return list of lists from foreach loop in R

Tags: r, list, foreach

I have a function which returns a list of two objects (a list `l` and a number `n`). I want to loop over this function in a `foreach` loop.

```
create_lists <- function(){
l = sample(100, 5)
n = sample(100, 1)
return(list(l=l, n=n))}
```

Because `create_lists` has a list as ouput, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189614/foreach-parallel-combine-function-for-multiple-outputs) told me to use a combine function which looks like this:

```
combine_custom <- function(list1, list2){
  ls = c(list1$l, list2$l)
  ns = c(list1$n, list2$n)
  return(list(l = ls, n = ns))
}
```

So now my `foreach` loop looks like this:

```
m = foreach(i=1:5, .combine = combine_custom)%do%{
   create_lists()}
```

My desired output would be:

```
m$l
[[1]]
[1] 100  25  86  21  28

[[2]]
[1] 78 37 79 41 61

[[3]]
[1] 73 22 78 94 13

[[4]]
[1] 15 28 76 78 52

[[5]]
[1] 32 93 92  2  1

m$n
[1] 52 56 3 79 82
```

But what I get is something like this:

```
$l
 [1] 84 28 75 59 68 84 28 75 59 68

$n
[1] 31 91 18 98 39
```

So I have two problems: 
1) Why is everything but two of the `l` lists dropped?
2) How can I make `m$l` to be a list of lists?

EDIT:
I tried another approach I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848172/appending-a-list-to-a-list-of-lists-in-r) which does not use `c`:

```
combine_custom <- function(list1, list2){
      ls = list1$l[[length(list1$l)+1]] = list(list2$l)
      ns = c(list1$n, list2$n)
      return(list(l = ls, n = ns))
    }
```

But this gave the same result as described above, to be exact:

```
$l
$l[[1]]
[1] 65 84 48 81 82


$n
[1] 88 79 92 36 71
```

Comment: In ```combine_custom```, do you mean ``` ls = c(list1$l, list2$l)``` instead of combining list2 with itself? That should solve problem (1). Problem (2) is because of using ```c``` to combine lists.

Comment: Yes thank you, that solved one msystery. But I am still stuck with the list of lists. What would you use instead? I tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848172/appending-a-list-to-a-list-of-lists-in-r) this, but with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another way which avoids the problem mentioned above, namely that `combine` has to create a new list first and later only append lists.
Also, the real function I am using actually returns a list of lists, so the following proved useful:

```
combine_custom <- function(list1, list2) {
     if (plotrix::listDepth(list1$l) > plotrix::listDepth(list2$l)) {
        ls  <- c(list1$l, list(list2$l))
    } else {
        ls <- c(list(list1$l), list(list2$l))
     }
     ns <- c(list1$n, list2$n)
     return(list(l = ls, n = ns))
}
```

This is not perfect if the function can return lists of varying nesting depths, but it works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Maria H., you solved my problem! The 'plotrix' package didn't work for me, but I used 'collapse' and it worked fine:

```
combine_custom1 <- function(a, b) {

  if (collapse::ldepth(a) > collapse::ldepth(b)) {

    ls <- c(a, list(b))

  } else {

    ls <- c(list(a), list(b))

  }

  return(ls)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `combine` part is giving a lot of trouble, because on the first iteration, it needs to make a list out of two lists , but on the second iteration, it needs to append one list as an element to a list of lists.

Another approach (may or may not work depending on the size of your actual data/problem) is to use the `purrr` package for working with lists:

```
> m <- foreach(i=1:3)%do%{create_lists()}
> m
[[1]]
[[1]]$l
[1] 21 33 12 50 36

[[1]]$n
[1] 74


[[2]]
[[2]]$l
[1] 12 80 39 78  6

[[2]]$n
[1] 74


[[3]]
[[3]]$l
[1]  9 61 75 63 94

[[3]]$n
[1] 2


> purrr::transpose(m)
$l
$l[[1]]
[1] 21 33 12 50 36

$l[[2]]
[1] 12 80 39 78  6

$l[[3]]
[1]  9 61 75 63 94


$n
$n[[1]]
[1] 74

$n[[2]]
[1] 74

$n[[3]]
[1] 2
```

Hope that helps!